# why did not logout when I delete user accounts in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need redirect logout My app when user delete Accounts. using this UserController

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $users = User::findOrFail($id);
    $users->delete();

    Auth::logout();

    return Auth::logout();
    //redirect()->back()->with('info','Your Account has beed deleted successfully');
}
```

My delete button is this in index.blade.php

```
<button class="btn btn-circle btn-danger delete"
                      data-action="{{ url('users/' . $use->id) }}"
                      data-token="{{csrf_token()}}">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete
</button>
```

how can I fix this?

**updated answer**

```
 @if(isset($users))
                        @foreach($users as $use)
                        <h1>{{$use->username}}</h1>
                        <h1>{{$use->email}}</h1>
                        @endforeach
                        @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work for you:

```
<button class="btn btn-circle btn-danger delete"
   data-action="{{url('users')}}/{{$use->id}}"
   data-token="{{csrf_token()}}">
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete
</button>
```

Comment: did this but occured this error **ErrorException in Project.php line 19: Trying to get property of non-object**  this is Project.php line 19 **public function scopePersonal($query)
{
     return $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id); // line 19
   
}**

Comment: data-action="{{url('users')}}/{{$user->id}}"

Comment: can i see how u passed data in view?